# PHP: Convert date from Y-F-d format to Y-m-d format

Tags: php, date

I want to convert php date from **Y-F-d** format to **Y-m-d** format.
I use the code below.

```
<?php
$originalDate = "2014-March-03";
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($originalDate));
echo $newDate ;
?>
```

I get an output like

**2014-03-01**

When i convert the date  **"2014-Mar-03"**

```
<?php
$originalDate = "2014-Mar-03";
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($originalDate));
echo $newDate ;
?>
```

I get ouput like

**2014-03-03**

Why the first one does not give the correct result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)  class,

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-M-d', '2014-Mar-03');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-F-d', '2014-March-03');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/j7he1i)**.

**Reason:** As strtotime only accept date in specific format (`ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD)`), It want be able to recognize all formats of date we provide to it. [Read Note](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-notes) section of strtotime function for more details.

Whereas DateTime::createFromFormat function returns new DateTime object formatted according to the specified format and than we can use that object to convert in any format of date.

Comment: i agree with your answer but why date() is not working?

Comment: Because strtotime only accept date in specific format. It want be able to recognize all formats of date you provide to it. [Read Note](http://in3.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-notes) section of strtotime function.

Comment: i think you need to add this in your answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `F` instead of `M` in date function

```
$originalDate = "2014-Mar-03";
$newDate = date("Y-F-d", strtotime($originalDate));
echo $newDate ;
```

`F` is for full textual representation of a month, such as January or March.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$originalDate = "2014-March-03";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-F-d', $originalDate);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Output is:

```
2014-03-03
```